# ASP.NET Session State - Works In Firefox & IE8, not in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, session, iis, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to pass four items using session state as follows:

```
    protected void createFirstNameSessionVariable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["FirstName"] = firstName.Value;
        Session.Timeout = 60;
        TextBox1.Text = Session["FirstName"].ToString(); 
    }

    protected void createLastNameSessionVariable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["LastName"] = lastName.Value;
        Session.Timeout = 60;
        TextBox2.Text += Session["LastName"].ToString();
    }
    protected void createIdSessionVariable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["FacebookId"] = facebookId.Value;
        Session.Timeout = 60;
        TextBox3.Text += Session["FacebookId"].ToString();
    }
    protected void createEmailSessionVariable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["Email"] = email.Value;
        Session.Timeout = 60;
        TextBox4.Text += Session["Email"].ToString();
    }
```

In Firefox and IE8, I can get them on another page using the following:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["FacebookId"] != null)
        {
            name = Session["FacebookId"].ToString();
            studentButton.Text = name;
        }
        else
        {
            studentButton.Text = "fail";
        }
    }
```

In Chrome, however, the button label is set to fail because the session variable has a null value on the receiving end.

On IIS 7.0 Manager, the session state is currently set to "In Process"
Mode: Use Cookies
Name: ASP.NET_SessionId
Time out: 20 mins

Use hosting identity for impersonation is checked.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have allowed cookies in Chrome.

Comment: - Cookies are allowed in Chrome. I should also mention that this code is running in a Facebook App.